# Unable to run container with local-persist plugin

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I run `docker-compose up -d` seems to start my container but then stops for some unknown reason.

When I do `docker ps` I do not see any containers running.

Before I started using `docker-volume-local-persist` (https://github.com/CWSpear/local-persist/) the container would run without any issues.

Why am I unable to keep the container running?

Here are some details of my system:

docker ps -a

```
Path Called...    Returned path /var/docker/data/local-persist/entry/config/
Path Called...    Returned path /var/docker/data/local-persist/entry/log/
Path Called...    Returned path /var/docker/data/local-persist/entry/data/
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS               NAMES
4646b189d784        docker_entry        "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   About an hour ago   Exited (1) About an hour ago
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:

  entry:
    build: ../../../www/PropolisDockerWebEntry/jessie
    #    depends_on:
    #  - consul
    container_name: entry
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - entry-log:/var/log/entry/:rw
      - entry-data:/usr/share/nginx/html/:rw
      - entry-config:/etc/nginx/:rw
    networks:
      apps:
        aliases:
          - entry

networks:
  apps:

volumes:
  entry-log:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: /var/docker/data/local-persist/entry/log/
  entry-data:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: /var/docker/data/local-persist/entry/data/
  entry-config:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: /var/docker/data/local-persist/entry/config/
```

docker-compose up -d

```
Get Called...     Found docker_entry-log
Get Called...     Found docker_entry-log
Get Called...     Found docker_entry-data
Get Called...     Found docker_entry-data
Get Called...     Found docker_entry-config
Get Called...     Found docker_entry-config
Path Called...    Returned path /var/docker/data/local-persist/entry/config/
Path Called...    Returned path /var/docker/data/local-persist/entry/log/
Path Called...    Returned path /var/docker/data/local-persist/entry/data/
Starting entry ... 
Starting entry
Mount Called...   Mounted docker_entry-config
Path Called...    Returned path /var/docker/data/local-persist/entry/config/
Mount Called...   Mounted docker_entry-log
Path Called...    Returned path /var/docker/data/local-persist/entry/log/
Mount Called...   Mounted docker_entry-data
Starting entry ... done
Unmounted docker_entry-data
Path Called...    Returned path /var/docker/data/local-persist/entry/data/
Unmount Called... Unmounted docker_entry-config
Path Called...    Returned path /var/docker/data/local-persist/entry/config/
Unmount Called... Unmounted docker_entry-log
Path Called...    Returned path /var/docker/data/local-persist/entry/log/
```

docker volume ls

```
List Called...    Found 3 volumes
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local-persist       docker_entry-config
local-persist       docker_entry-data
local-persist       docker_entry-log
```

ps aux | grep docker

```
root      6690  0.0  0.9  44752  9032 pts/0    Sl   21:55   0:00 /usr/bin/docker-volume-local-persist
root      7418  0.2  4.5 327824 44856 pts/0    Sl   22:25   0:01 dockerd
root      7424  0.1  1.1 221600 11776 ?        Ssl  22:25   0:00 docker-containerd -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --metrics-interval=0 --start-timeout 2m --state-dir /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd --shim docker-containerd-shim --runtime docker-runc
```

dockerd --version

```
Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87
```

docker --version

```
Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87
```

lsb_release -a

```
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu5-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu5-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu5-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu5-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty
```

Comment: Use `journalctl -n 10 -f` and then start the compose, scan the logs generated for errors

Comment: This helps. Thank you.

Comment: Do post the details of how you solved the issue

Comment: They are multiple issue. Well that's what it seems. But I will when I am clear on what all the issues are.